# onOptionsSelected is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to hide the menu in the TableLayout with ViewPager I want the menu only in the solutions tab. I used the onPrepareOptionsmenu  to hide the menu in tabs except the solutions tab. the thing is my onOptionsItemSelected is not working.

code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
    inf.inflate(R.menu.simpleadd,menu);

    // +getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.simpleadd, menu);
    onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (viewpager.getCurrentItem()==0){
        menu.findItem(R.id.simpleadd).setVisible(false);
    } else if(viewpager.getCurrentItem()==1){
        menu.findItem(R.id.simpleadd).setVisible(false);
    } else if(viewpager.getCurrentItem()==2){
        menu.findItem(R.id.simpleadd).setVisible(true);
    } else if(viewpager.getCurrentItem()==3){
        menu.findItem(R.id.simpleadd).setVisible(false);
    }else if(viewpager.getCurrentItem()==4){
        menu.findItem(R.id.simpleadd).setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
              switch (item.getItemId()){
                  case R.id.simpleadd:
                      startActivity(new Intent(this,NewSolution.class));
           }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: Inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, you type `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)`, is this typo or not? Because I think it should be `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)`

Comment: did that...not working...but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have used the layout's name in the switch case of onOptionsItemSelected.

Use menu item's id instead.

Comment: they both are same actually

Comment: @Arpittodewale Please return true within that case.

Comment: till switch state, the debug breakpoint is correct, the error comes in the case.

Answer (score 0):

> First, you need to get item id and then set compare with layout ids,
>   this helps you to set the functionality. Please find the below sample
>   code for your reference.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();

             if (id == R.id.simpleadd) {
                    // execute your code here
    }  

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```